# Overvoltage protection for DC controlled Device

Tags: power, circuit-design, components, zener, over-voltage-protection

i've designed this schematic using a simple buck converter (LM2596) for my board that powers up some leds and board peripherals.

The board will work at 5V with maximum current draw of 2.5A.

Now, as you can see in the schematic, i've already added a reverse voltage protection using SS34 (D6) diode ([Datasheet here](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1809052012_MDD-Microdiode-Electronics-SS34_C8678.pdf)), what i want to implement is the overvoltage protection, i want that if there is a voltage input of more than 15V the external peripheral (marked with netflag +12V-POE) will not start blowing up (as the external peripheral maximum voltage rating is 15V).

What i can use? a Zener (in this case what part you recommend) or something different?

[image]

Comment: The LM2596 is rated up to 40 odd volts so what are you actually trying to achieve here? D5 doesn't seem a very sensible idea. What are you trying to protect from overvoltage and what has this got to do with the LM2596?

Comment: The D5 might not be here, i have removed it, is pretty useless.
I need to protect a device that is wired in parallel to the LM2596 using the netflag +12V-POE and the maximum rating voltage is 15V

Comment: Your title is *"LM2596 - Overvoltage protection"* - can you explain why this is your title?

Comment: thanks Andy, i've changed the title of the original post

Comment: But, as far as I can tell, your question has got nothing to do with the LM2596 and its ability to produce a 5 volt output rail irrespective of it feeding a load that takes 2.5 amps or not. Why are you still mentioning this in the question - it just wastes people's time wading through the swamp.

Comment: If you *expect* operators to apply >15v, you could also run a buck-boost or SEPIC converter in front of all of this to supply 12v from a wider input range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you only need to protect the +12V-POE output, we can ignore the LM2596 circuit.

A fuse and zener will protect against many faults, but depending on your current requirements, there may be a sweet spot where a slight overload will burn out the zener before the fuse blows.

An SCR crowbar circuit with a properly sized SCR is robust enough to handle any situation.

The zener voltages in the schematic will need to be adjusted appropriately. The default values in the simulator are not suitable.

https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/thyristor-scr-triac/overvoltage-protection-crowbar-circuit.php

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk5XBi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>